# Python 3.8: class object data still around after using del

Tags: python-3.x, object, memory, memory-leaks

I have a class that does some stuff;
`class IdoStuff:`.

In a loop, an object of class `IdoStuff` is created, does some stuff, and is deleted:

```
for i in range(0,50):
   obj = IdoStuff()     # initialize object
   obj.doStuff()        # does something
   obj.doMoreStuff()    # does another thing
   del obj
```

Everything works as needed for the first iteration, but on the second iteration, I can see with my debugger that once the second object is created, the variables/data of the first object are still there.

What's going on? I thought I deleted it with `del obj`. I want to create a new object with each iteration.

Comment: Are you sure your debugger isn't just refreshing "badly"?
Try adding a `print(obj)` statement or something similar after creating it, that might help.
And if you have a live evaluator which you can use during breakpoints, try accessing attributes of `obj` which aren't supposed to exist yet but may be around from the last iteration. 

Both of these things (especially the 2nd if possible should help you to verify if stuff is indeed remaining from previous iterations)

Comment: @Campiotti I don't think that's the case. I tried that with no luck. With my debugger (using Pycharm) I can see the object be deleted after `del obj` is called, but once I create another object, I can see that all of the data is back as it was

Comment: Trying it out on my Pycharm as well, getting the same visual issue in the debugger, I'll check code-wise if attribs are actually still there. 
Nevermind, I wasn't initializing the class so the attributes were staying, fixed that and the issue doesn't occur anymore for me.

Comment: By initialize, do you mean I should do something else rather than `obj = IdoStuff()`

Comment: nono I was referring to the fact that I accidentally did `obj = IdoStuff` instead of `obj = IdoStuff()` which ended up adding attributes to an imported class which then stayed since it wasn't an instance but a reference to the class itself.


You can ignore my previous comment basically, I'd just advise you to try out the answer I've posted below - we should be able to see conclusive proof to if there is any leakage of any type.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your code to the following

```
for i in range(0,50):
   obj = IdoStuff()     # initialize object
   try:
     print(obj.my_check_attrib)
   except Exception:
     print('failed to access obj.my_check_attrib')
   obj.my_check_attrib = 123
   obj.doStuff()        # does something
   obj.doMoreStuff()    # does another thing
   del obj
```

If there is indeed any actual leakage then you should only see the error-text printed once and the attribute values 49 times, if there is no leakage then only the error-text will be shown in your console 50 times.